# Flask python assertion error: unimplemented method 'GET'

Tags: python, get, flask

Can someone please explain to me the difference between these two blocks of code. The first one works while the latter throws the error which I've indicated in the title.

```
def login_required(method):
@functools.wraps(method)
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'username' in flask.session:
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        flask.flash("A login is required to see the page!")
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
return wrapper
```

AND

```
def login_required(method):
@functools.wraps(method)
def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
    if "username" in flask.session:
        return method(*args,**kwargs)
    else:
        flask.flash("A login is required to see the page!")
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
    return wrapper
```

Comment: i think you got the indentation wrong on both versions, see fuctools [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code sample, you correctly return the `wrapper` function at the end of the `login_required` function.

In the second code sample you've got the `return wrapper` *inside* the `wrapper` function itself. Just de-dent that last line and you should be all set.